# Get node name given to a USB by ACM Driver

Tags: c, linux, usb, device-driver

I have two usb devices that are recognized by the ACM driver and I’m developing a program in C to communicate with them. As the command for each one are different, I need to know the name given for each one (usb/acm/X).

How can I get this name given the vendorId and productId? I have tried parsing dmesg text but in some cases I may have the two lines “ttyACMX: USB ACM device” one after the other.
I could parse the order each device shows its name in dmesg and take the same number in the “ttyACMX” but this force me to parse also the disconnections messages and all becomes a bit dirty.

I’ve seen that the information I need is in the structure tty_driver created for each device and I’m sure I can have this information easier than parsing dmesg.

Can someone point me out int the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`libudev` (C) might be a solution, also have a look at the source of `ModemManager` daemon (C, glib based)

Comment: I'm in a embedded environment so resources are quite limited but I'll take a look to modemMananager.

Answer (score 0):

Use libudev or some higher-level library like gudev (GLib-based libudev). Don't use ModemManager unless your devices are really mobile broadband (2G/3G/4G) modems.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread to be helpful: http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=6741

You can make a udev rule file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` that has a rule like this:

> KERNEL=="ttyACM0", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",
>   ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ffb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="008c",
>   ATTRS{serial}=="00053419", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="TTYS_002"

I think this will make a device named `/dev/TTYS_002` when you plug in a CDC ACM device that has the specified vendor ID, product ID, and serial number.

Comment: I can't add libudev. I don't have access to the chaintool. Anyway, thank you for the attempt

Comment: What's a "chaintool"?  Can't you ask your system administrator to add a udev rule for you, or use sudo to do it yourself?

Comment: I meant tool chain. And no, it isn't possible

Comment: I don't understand:  If you're developing a program in C as you stated earlier, you already have a toolchain that can compile C programs for you.  Also, a toolchain isn't needed for adding a udev rule; you just need to have a text editor like `nano` and you need root permissions so you can modify the `/etc/udev/rules.d` folder.  It would help if you explain what your end goal is, what constraints you have, and why.  Why exactly is it impossible for you to add a udev rule?

Comment: Because the kernel doesn't have udev library

Comment: I asked this one year ago and it was for a set-top-box. We have almost left the development there. Thank you anyway.